# How do you craft a redstone lamp and a daylight sensor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried spawning in redstone lamps and daylight sensors and it worked, but I don't know how to craft them. What are the crafting recipes for redstone lamps and daylight sensors?

Comment: Please try and do some research before posting a question.  This is a really basic question that just requires a quick look to the [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki) to determine.

Comment: Plus, asking two questions in one is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the information for both of these here:

- Daylight sensor: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_sensor
- Redstone lamp: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_lamp